# Will this laptop run on ubuntu?

Tags: laptop

I have found a nice laptop but now i am wondering if [this laptop](http://www.alternate.nl/html/product/Notebooks_Intel%28R%29/ALTERNATE/17CL35_Basis_III/543867/?tn=BUILDERS&l1=Notebooks) ([translation](http://translate.google.nl/translate?hl=nl&sl=nl&tl=en&u=http://www.alternate.nl/html/product/Notebooks_Intel%28R%29/ALTERNATE/17CL35_Basis_III/543867/?tn=BUILDERS&l1=Notebooks)) can run ubuntu.

Comment: Beste, de Nederlandse Ubuntu forum is beschikbaar op http://forum.ubuntu-nl.org/. Daar kun je misschien ook advies krijgen.

Comment: sure it will 'run' ubuntu, why wouldn't it? ... if you mean whether or not it will support it's onboard wifi/bluetooth/webcam/etc is another matter. However that site does not list details on those. It also fails to list much more basic details, like the CPU and RAM on it, on my mind that causes alarms to go off -- ie. I'd stear clear of that product, or if they do this on all their stuff, I'd drop that store altogether. I'd go with a store that does list those very important details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

17CL35... that looks like a [BTO](http://www.bto.eu/) notebook, details on that model can be found [here](http://www.bto.eu/html/detail_home.asp?PartnerID=1&lang=nl&DisplayPartnerID=1&ProductID=519). The specifications are almost equal to my notebook (I've a 17CL34).

Everything works **except** for the nVidia discrete card. Optimus [does **not** work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work) on Ubuntu and other Linux-based systems and nVidia has [no plans to support them](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=2183477#post2183477). There are [ways to use the card though](http://hybrid-graphics-linux.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Bumblebee), although the experience on using it may differ.

Some notes about the BTO notebook (which is in fact a [Clevo B7130](http://www.clevo.com.tw/en/e-services/download/USRManualOut.asp?model=B7130)) I own:

- the Plymouth splash screen is text-only in Natty, this is related to bug [770371](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/770371) which has [a workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/770371/comments/4).
- The BIOS is a very limited Phoenix SecureCore one, there is no way to disable/ toggle the graphics card.
- The Optimus button on the notebook <del>does nothing</del> is handled by software, which should not be specific to this model but all models in general. I wrote the [clevo-wmi](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/acpi-stuff/tree/master/clevo-wmi) module (not to be confused to other modules that are named the `clevo-wmi`) that can be used to change the LED color and assign custom functionality to it (e.g. "Lock screen").
- Fn + F[89] for toggling brightness do <del>not</del> work (bug [806032](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/806032) got fixed), brightness can be controlled by the applet too.

Comment: Based on the fight you'll have in order to use what you're paying for (Optimus), I would personally avoid this one.

Comment: I know this is an old thread. For that very reason I like to say that there is Bumblebee and Primus. As well as Nvidia Prime under Linux now a days (2014/2015). Futhermore, the most thinks work very well out of the box (like bluetooth & wifi). Even webcam works out of the box, do not forget the fn+10 to active the webcam.